# Use mouse to move a zoomed image in a frame

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a scale which controls the zoom-in and out of an image in a Tkinter frame. I want to use the mouse to click on image and move zoomed image in the frame, however its not working. Below is my code I am using. Any help to get it to work will be appreciated. Thanks in Advance. Below is my current code.

```
root = Tk()
canvas = tk.Canvas(root, height=500, width=500)
canvas.pack()
frame = customtkinter.CTkFrame(master=root, width=300, height=200)
frame.place(x=10, y=10)

canvas.bind('<ButtonPress-1>', move_from)
canvas.bind('<B1-Motion>', move_to)

###putting image on frame label###
def Image():
    global img, img_label, IMG
    IMG = Image.open('im.png')
    img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(IMG.resize((280, 280), Image.ANTIALIAS))
    img_label = Label(frame, image=img)
    img_label.image = img
    img_label.place(x=200, y=0)
    img_label.pack(side=TOP, padx=20, pady=50)
    return img_label

#### zoom function ####
def zoom_img(zoom):
    global Img
    newsize = (IMG.size[0]* int(zoom), 
                IMG.size[1]*int(zoom))
    scaledIMG = IMG.resize(newsize, Image.LINEAR)
    Img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(scaledIMG)
    img_label.configure(image=Img, width=200, height=220)
    img_label.place(x=80, y=0)
    img_label.pack(side=TOP, padx=5, pady=5)

### scale ###
scale_label = customtkinter.CTkLabel(master=root, text="Zoom", width=50, fg_color="gray80").place(x=85, y=130)

var = StringVar()
scale = tk.Scale(root, variable=var, orient='horizontal', from_=1, to=5, length=200, resolution=1, command=zoom_img)
scale.place(x=85, y=140)

def move_from(event):
    canvas.scan_mark(event.x, event.y)

def move_to(event):
    canvas.scan_dragto(event.x, event.y, gain=1)
```

Comment: What does "not working" mean? What does it do that is different than what you expect?

Comment: Every time you move your mouse you end up creating a new label with a new image. Is that intentional? Why create a new image every time the mouse moves?

Comment: @BryanOakley, it's not working like when I click the image and move, it doesn't move.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're attempting to use the canvas scanning feature, that that only works on canvas objects. You aren't creating canvas objects, you're creating labels and are placing them on the canvas with `pack`. You won't be able to scroll or scan anything added to a canvas with `pack`, `place`, or `grid`.

For you to be able to use the scanning feature you have to make the image an object on the canvas with the canvas' `create_image` method.

Here is an example showing how to use the scanning feature of the canvas. Note: the scan feature doesn't move the image, it moves the viewport in the same way that scrollbars do. The actual coordinate of the image doesn't change.

```
import tkinter as tk

def main():
    root = tk.Tk()

    image = tk.PhotoImage(data = image_data)

    canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=400, height=400, bg="white")
    canvas.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

    canvas.create_image(10, 10, anchor="nw", image=image)

    canvas.bind("<ButtonPress-1>", drag_start)
    canvas.bind("<B1-Motion>", drag_move)

    root.mainloop()

def drag_start(event):
    event.widget.scan_mark(event.x, event.y)

def drag_move(event):
    event.widget.scan_dragto(event.x, event.y, gain=1)

image_data = """
    R0lGODlhGAAYAPZvAAIaLgwmOwcnQQcoQBMxSBc4VBQ6Vhk7VRY9WhY+XSI4RxJC
    ZRRCZi9KYSFNbzJUbSJOcCZVeiZUeyBWfy1Zei5afB1Wgh1XgyFXgDpjgSVjkyZl
    liZnmCxrmixsmjZtlSptoCpuoSxxqCxzqjh1oTV3qDR4qD5/rjV8tDV+tUFlgUZp
    hFNwhVVyh0ZzlUh7nnB8hUF8pkJ8pkx+oTuBuFmBn3SEkHeOn3mNnUeBqUiBqUqD
    q1CBpFKCpVuDoVyEokeGs0eHs0aKvkaMvlGOuGqKom+Pp3yUpziEwTiFwz2KxT+K
    xE6VylKUw1qaxV6fx0CQ0E+b1lCd1l6h0Wiq1Wyu12Wp22aq3FOi4F2s5WCt5W64
    7XW24Xu743u/6omfsZymroqhso6jtJynsJ2psaS1w6S2xIvH7YvI7d/h5ODi5eDk
    5+Dm6uLn7OPo7QAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
    AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACH+SUNvcHlyaWdodCBJTkNPUlMgR21iSCAod3d3Lmljb25l
    eHBlcmllbmNlLmNvbSkgLSBVbmxpY2Vuc2VkIHByZXZpZXcgaW1hZ2UAIfkEBQAA
    bwAsAAAAABgAGAAAB9eAb4KDhIWGh4iJiouMjY6PiGkwCgAACjBqj2ABBSw3Ny0H
    AWONYwIqYmFfX2FiKwNki2kEFEZFRba3RhUEa4o2Cy41NT/FPsMuDDaKDRYfLzM8
    PT0zMy8fFw2KBRoeJDI6Ojs5MSQdGwaKCCAmJ0FE8ERAJyUhCYoPIjRDTU5PT06a
    CKEx4oEiHBuWMJlCpUoVKlOYKOFwQxEbB0ikXOHSpQsXK1GSQGizyIwFKFq8oDnj
    JQsUDGYalYmAYsqWLVhSSIjpqM2RDBMuZDjiBpLRo0iTKjUaCAA7
"""

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: the image is created in the frame within the canvas. Can I use ```canvas.create_image``` method to create image in the frame?

Comment: You can use `canvas.create_image` to create an image in the canvas. I've updated the answer to include a working example.

Comment: Thanks Bryan, since I have created default frames, I created a canvas and placed it into the frame and then put the image on the canvas. It works for me. The frames are two so I created a canvas on the 2nd frame to add the image and move. When I use the mouse pointer to move the image of the first frame, its become inactive on the image on the 2nd frame even though I have created ```scan_mark()```  and ```scan_dragto()``` even for the 2nd canvas in the 2nd frame. Can the ```scan_mark```  and ```scan_dragto()``` be configured so that the mouse can work on images on both canvas at the same time

Comment: I have figured it out. I'm good now